How to check if an image is loaded if src was added later in the js code?
I have this dynamic code
dynamicBg.src = Dynamic_Content.Image_URL.Url; 
headline1.innerHTML = Dynamic_Content.Headline; 
headline2.innerHTML = Dynamic_Content.Headline2; 
headline3.innerHTML = Dynamic_Content.Headline3; 
fullHeadline.innerHTML = Dynamic_Content.fullHeadline;  
cta_1.innerHTML = Dynamic_Content.CTA;

So animation starts and the image appears later.
Any ideas on how to check if the image is loaded and then animate?
thanx!
I tried with a timer but I want to catch the event exactly

You can and should use the load event of the image. Attach the handler first, then update the src attribute.


var img = document.querySelector("img")
img.addEventListener("load", function(ev) {
  console.log("image loaded")
})
img.src = "https://picsum.photos/150"
<img>



